# Javascript indexOf a list for a targeted event in a unordered list giving the wrong index

Tags: javascript, queryselector

I am trying to get the index number of a 'li' element of a 'ul' from the html.
To do this I change the 'ul' into a list to get his children with:

```
[...ul.children]
```

However when I target any of the children I get a -1 as index instead of the correct index.
How to fix?

Is this due to the fact that the list items it's not empty and has a div or other elements inside?

Here is my javascript and my html:

```js
const ul = document.querySelector('ul');
ul.addEventListener('click', myFunc);

function myFunc(e) {
  const indexToShow = [...ul.children].indexOf(e.target);
  console.log(indexToShow);
  console.log(e.target);
}
```

```html
<ul class="calendar-list">
  <li class="list-item">
    <div class="fight-link">
      <span class="date">1 Dec 2022</span>
      <span class="fighters-name">JAY</span>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="list-item">
    <div class="fight-link">
      <span class="date">2 Dec 2022</span>
      <span class="fighters-name">Jo</span>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="list-item">
    <div class="fight-link">
      <span class="date">3 Dec 2022</span>
      <span class="fighters-name">Bob</span>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Are you sure that the ```e.target``` matches any of the elements in ```[...ul.children]``` array? Can you log the values of each?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The click evennt triggers on the `span`, but you're comparing against the `li`.

So you'll need to search for the `li` using `closest()` to match the elements:

```js
const ul = document.querySelector('ul');
ul.addEventListener('click', myFunc);

function myFunc(e) {
  const indexToShow = [...ul.children].indexOf(e.target.closest('li'));
  console.log(indexToShow);
}
```

```html
<ul class="calendar-list">
  <li class="list-item">
    <div class="fight-link">
      <span class="date">1 Dec 2022</span>
      <span class="fighters-name">JAY</span>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="list-item">
    <div class="fight-link">
      <span class="date">2 Dec 2022</span>
      <span class="fighters-name">Jo</span>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="list-item">
    <div class="fight-link">
      <span class="date">3 Dec 2022</span>
      <span class="fighters-name">Bob</span>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you, it's the first time I came across the" .closest ", it's going to be useful for many uses. Appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

here is how you can achive this

```
const ul = document.querySelector('ul');
  ul.addEventListener('click', myFunc);

  function myFunc(e) {
    const indexToShow = [...ul.children].indexOf(e.path[2]);
    console.log(indexToShow);
    console.log(e.target);
  }
```